# j2me no of threads

Tags: multithreading, java-me

I am developing a j2me map based application. Screen is divided into a grid of images and I have to request these images from a server. This can be threaded. What is the maximum no of threads that I can spawn in a j2me midlet? Is there a way to arrive at this no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It purely depends on the device. Some devices have more numbers of threads, some less. Typically most phones would support from 5 to 10 threads, but these numbers may vary. A word of caution is that the more the number of threads, the less the application responsiveness is

Answer (score 1):

If your are talking about max. number of simultaneously requests to server, most device would allow only one. And, I think, that if some devices would allow to create several connections in a time, on hardware level they would make only one, so you'd better

- open connection
- wait for response
- read data
- close connection
- open another connection
- ...

I know that Google map for j2me uses sockets, which heavily improve download speed.

Also, try looking at [nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com) and [j2memap](http://j2memap.8motions.com/)